# Blocked WP stylesheet by robot.txt

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm actually a little confused on this. My google analytic is giving me an error saying that they cannot enter the CSS and JS in my site so ranking or placement in search engine can be negatively affected by this. I did lose placement and fell down 3 pages so I assume it is the reason why. It says it is a line in the robot.txt, maybe I don't understand wordpress enough but it says this is stopping it

```
  Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

Now I would think the CSS stylesheet for the front end is not going to be in the wp-admin folder. This is supposed to be for the admin panel right? So why would it look for that css instead of - for example: `www.domain.com/css/style.css`  ??  -  Why would it look for it in `www.domain.com/wp-admin/css/style.css`

If I change  `Disallow: /wp-admin/` to  Allow or take it out completely, will that let robots crawl my full admin panel which I do not want?

Will that present some vulnerabilities in any other way?

Could it be that during a plugin update, maybe the tag in the head could have been changed incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like webcrawlers are trying to access a page that uses the admin CSS, not necessarilly meaning that the admin CSS is used for regular templates. You didn't specify for which URL you get this warning (if they even tell you that). See you pages' sources, check if the wrong CSS link is really there.

---

> If I change  Disallow: /wp-admin/ to Allow or take it out completely, will that let robots crawl my full admin panel which I do not want?

`robots.txt` is used to help robots navigate areas of your website, but it's in no way blocking their access to it. Good robots will obey the rules you set, but the bad ones don't have to. They can't crawl your full admin unless they have the credentials.

> Will that present some vulnerabilities in any other way?

Not really, it might make it obvious that your site is WP, but that's already very obvious to all the WP websites (meta tags, common url structure, visiting /wp-admin, etc).

> Could it be that during a plugin update, maybe the tag in the head could have been changed incorrectly?

Only if it's a really poorly written plugin, that would never happen normally. Again, check if your front-end pages are really requesting that CSS.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I can't help you more before you trace the origin of that request.

Comment: I will be looking for it and will get back to your as soon as I find it. Thanks again!